# Define array index after function call

Tags: php, arrays, function

In other languages such as C# and JavaScript, I am able to access the index of an array with a function call such as

```
getMyArray()[0]
```

This would allow me to access the first index of the result instead of passing back the entire array and then setting the result.

However this shortcut does not work with PHP. Is there a way to get this shortcut?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to be running PHP 5.4 in order to use [array de-referencing](http://razvantudorica.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/array-dereferencing-support-in-php-5-4-0/).

Comment: Also, here's the [new features list](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) for migrating to 5.4.

Comment: So there is no support for this in 5.3.8?

Answer (score 3):

```
// PHP 5.4
$item = getMyArray()[0];

// Older than 5.4: (not recommended)
list($a)   = getMyArray();  // getMyArray()[0]
list(, $b) = getMyArray();  // getMyArray()[1]
```