# PHP While Loop for Multidimensional Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

So i tried to loop through bunch of arrays using the while loop.
So it does not work like this, how does it work?

```
    while($x<$sQuery($SERVER)['number'])
    {
        $o = $o . "<Server>
      <Name>".$sQuery($SERVER)[$x]['name']."</Name>
      <DNS>".$sQuery($SERVER)[$x]['ip']."</DNS>
    <Lat>0</Lat>
      <Long>0</Long>
      <Usage>-1</Usage>
      <RankRequired>0</RankRequired>
    </Server>"
        x++;
    }
}
```

The error is in this line(s):

```
      <Name>".$sQuery($SERVER)[$x]['name']."</Name>
      <DNS>".$sQuery($SERVER)[$x]['ip']."</DNS>
```

The `[$x]` is not allowed and i do not know how i can loop through them, any ideas?

Comment: x++;  need to be `$x++;`  Also `;` missed too

Comment: where's the semicolon after the </Server>" ?
also, what is "x++"; ? maybe $x++; ?

Comment: I don't recomment using $sQuery($SERVER). This is running that function over and over, every iteration. Better do it once before the loop and just use it statically.

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? You need to be running PHP 5.4 or later to use an index after a function call. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767976/define-array-index-after-function-call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm answering my own question (kinda).
The comments helped me a lot.
The thing is.. i should go to sleep because i am too tired for programming.

```
function ListServersXML($SERVER)
{
    $x = 0;
    $o = "";
    $s = sQuery($SERVER);
    while($x<$s['number'])
    {
        $o = $o . "<Server>
      <Name>".$s[$x]['name']."</Name>
      <DNS>".$s[$x]['ip']."</DNS>
    <Lat>0</Lat>
      <Long>0</Long>
      <Usage>-1</Usage>
      <RankRequired>0</RankRequired>
    </Server>";
        $x++;
    }
    return $o;
}
```

(btw this is my full function)

Comment: it's your responsibility to provide full code. It's not a good practice to hide code and then answer your question itself by showing full code (while others comment and answer resolved your problem)

Comment: Why don't you want to use `foreach`?

Comment: @Barmar as I already said, he has the elements he needs AND the `["number"]` element on the same level. You can go with `foreach` but you will have to ignore the `"number"` key then, an extra line.

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite it this way:-

```
$s = $sQuery($SERVER);

for($i=0; $i<$s['number']; $i++)
{
    $o .= "<Server><Name>".$s[$i]['name']."</Name>
           <DNS>".$s[$i]['ip']."</DNS><Lat>0</Lat><Long>0</Long><Usage>-1</Usage>
           <RankRequired>0</RankRequired></Server>";
}
```

Comment: Why not use `foreach`?

Comment: @Barmar Because there are the elements he needs AND the `["number"]` element on the same level. You can go with `foreach` but you will have to ignore the `"number"` key then, an extra line.